# Rails - How to structure an apps views files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a folder named public with an controller. There I but all the code I want the public to see. I am rendering actions. But in the URL it gets /public/ how do I remove it. I have made a page for each category that I have.

And is an way to change the url if example the action is named one. Is it so possible to change it to "rails-exammple". or is it better to name the actions after urls.

And what is the most convenient way to structure a simple app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done by setting up your routes correctly. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

This can help you to make a dry application : [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)

And I recommend to use [haml-rails](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails) for a beautiful code :)